# Python QT how to visualise that the button is clicked

Tags: python, qt, qt-creator, pyqt5

I have a `QtCreator` generated gui. After import i am setting images to the buttons and when i click them the button below probably indicates the click but the `QIcon` doesn't change in any way. Is there a way to make it visible?
This is my button code:

```
 self.pushButton.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('artwork/player_rew'))
 self.pushButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(48, 48))
 self.pushButton.setStyleSheet('QPushButton{border: 0px solid;}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `:pressed` [pseudo-state](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-pseudo-states) in your style sheet to specify the behaviour when the button is pressed:

```
self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("""
    QPushButton{
        border: 0px solid;
    }
    QPushButton:pressed {
        border: 0px solid;
        image: url(some_different_image);
        background-color: red;
    }
""")
```

More information can also be found in the [Qt Style Sheets Examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-a-qpushbutton-using-the-box-model)